# Where do I find SessionRegistry bean in spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring-boot application which use spring security, and I want to expire some session so that users need to re-log. After some digging, I should be able to do this with like

```
List<Object> loggedUsers = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
    for (Object principal : loggedUsers) {
        if (principal instanceof User) {
            final User loggedUser = (User) principal;
            if (user.getUsername().equals(loggedUser.getUsername())) {
                List<SessionInformation> sessionsInfo = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false);
                if (null != sessionsInfo && sessionsInfo.size() > 0) {
                    for (SessionInformation sessionInformation : sessionsInfo) {
                        sessionInformation.expireNow();
                            sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessionInformation.getSessionId());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I what to be able to do this in a @Service class. I thought there should be a `SessionRegistry` bean created by either spring-boot or spring security. Therefore I add

```
@Autowired
SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
```

but this throw a bean not found exception.
Then I try to create a `SessionRegistry` bean in my spring security configuration class.

```
@Bean SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() 
{ return new SessionRegistryImpl(); }
```

I got this bean in my service, but `getAllPrincipals()` return empty.
I think it is because this bean is not the same bean instance which is really being use by the application for login & session.

So, my question is where does this session registry object is being created and how do I wire it into my service?

spring security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    JdbcUserDetailsManager detailManager;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
        detailManager = (JdbcUserDetailsManager) auth.getDefaultUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/service", "/test", "/test2", ".resources/**", "/firmware/**", "/public/**", "/mycallback")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();

    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager()
    {
        return detailManager;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try adding [HttpSessionEventPublisher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/session/HttpSessionEventPublisher.html)          listener. Or if you have configured security initializer (See [AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.html) then you can add this listener by returning true from its `enableHttpSessionEventPublisher()` method.

Comment: what do I do after getting the publisher? how does it related to session registry?

Comment: `SessionRegistryImpl` bean implementation that you tried does the cleanup when a session is destroyed. The session destroyed event is triggered by `HttpSessionEventPublisher`.  One more thing that I missed earlier is that this bean should be configured in `AppSecurityConfig` as well. See [Querying the SessionRegistry for currently authenticated users and their sessions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/session-mgmt.html#list-authenticated-principals). You can add it as `and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(-1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry)`.